# How to call a Button from another view with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I'm using [this repo](https://github.com/gali8/G8SliderStep/tree/swift_2.3) but it doesn't have any function to alert me when the slider changes its value so I tried to do it myself.

First I tried to do it with the slider's action but I want only the value when the user will stop sliding which is an Int(the slider's action returned me a lot of values such as 1.2,1.3,1.4 etc).

I found a way to take the value when the user will stop sliding from a function that's inside this repo like this:

```
    internal func didMoveSliderStepValue(sendValueChangedEvent: Bool = false) {
            let intValue = Int(round(self.value))
            let floatValue = Float(intValue)

            print(intValue) //It prints only when the user stops sliding
            //a function to call after taking the value
            callTheButton()

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.35, animations: {
                self.setValue(floatValue, animated: true)
            }) { (fin) in
                self.setThumbForSliderValue(floatValue)
                if sendValueChangedEvent {
                    self.sendActionsForControlEvents(.ValueChanged)
                }
            }
        }

func callTheButton(){
     buttonFromMainView()
}
```

Now I want to trigger a button (buttonFromMainView) that I have in my main view.

So my question is this:

Can I call the button from the swift file that the repo has? 
Or can I take only the value when the user ends sliding from UISlider functions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't call a button, also, you can try to call it's method target

Comment: You can use NSNotificationCenter to fire a method that call your button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want easily access value after user finish touch you can set (for example in viewDidLoad)

```
isContinous
```

property of your G8SliderStep (and any UISlider) and then implement valueChanged function like for any other UISlider

```
@IBAction func valueChanged (sender: G8SliderStep)
{
    // Your value will be like 2.3325 so you want to round it
    let newValue = round(sender.value)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer i will test it in about an hour can you please edit your answer with more details how can i do it? Thanks

Comment: I can't understand how can I use isContinous

Comment: isContinous is property of UISlider. In your case you just type myStepSlider.isContinous = false